# Get default Helix keymapping file

Tags: editor, helix

I love Helix editor, but really don't like vim editing ways, like insert/command mode (why not `Ctrl-S` for saving rather than `Esc`, `:`, `w`? Three keystrokes instead of one?)

Fortunately I can remap key shortcuts, but I would like to get a complete, default `.toml` file so that I can do comprehensive job of remapping to a different layout.

I found only this: https://github.com/helix-editor/helix/blob/master/helix-term/src/commands.rs

Is there a way to get or generate it in Helix?